# Magento 2.0 - What determines when a global option is displayed in the product edit form?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I am very new to magento and I am trying to understand what determines when the Custom Stock Status will be an option when editing a product. I only find one file where there is some sort of get attribute text for it and when temporarily making it some custom text and clearing the cache, the label does not update. I think my biggest problem is where to look in the code like what files etc. What code file(s) determine what gets shown when editing a product  (catalog/product/edit/id/1041/) What tables may be involved that determines what Global config settings are to be used? I am not seeing this Global Config at all in the CMS unless I am looking in the wrong place which is totally possible. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to are attributes in Magento. You don't need to edit code and it's not good practice in this instance to do so. It would just be over written in an upgrade unless you created a custom extension and put your code there.

In this case you can edit the existing or create a new attribute set.

As far as attribute sets go you can either use the default attribute set, which is what you are most likely using, or you can create custom attribute sets to work with modules you created or you can extend the attribute set if you want some kind of color or size choose combo for example if you wanted to sell T-shirts that came in different size and colors.

I don't recommend editing the default attribute set as you may want that down the line, but you can clone it and add remove items as needed.

Go to stores > Product > Attribute

Select "Default" to see the default attribute set you are using.

Here you can see all the attributes the default set has.

[image]

Then go back to the panel at stores > Product > Attribute and hit the button "Add Attribute set"

[image]

Here you can name it and add/remove all the ones you want or don't want.

Then finally you need to assign this attribure set to the products that are going to use it.

Do that by going to Catalog > Products and assign the attribute set to the product.

[image]

Comment: This put me on the correct track thanks so much :) When I do try to update the attribute set I get some tinymce JS error and the please wait just spins for a long time.

Comment: Are you running Magento 2 locally or on the web? If running local on windows the issue you describe could be related to a symlinks issue

Comment: I am running on the web. What is the symlinks issue?

Comment: The symlinks issues happens running locally on windows. You edit a line in di.xml but that wont help you

Comment: I can tell you that some products allow me to update the attribute set and others do not.

Comment: hmmm, that's weird. Did you import products from an older version of Magento?

Comment: I was not involved until recently but I think someone copied products via a database copy or something so I guess perhaps data is wrong or something. I was hoping I could fix it once and for all.